# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1 in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

so I make a server in nodejs to connect with mongodb, from the start I use it until tomorrow is working fine, but today when I use it there is this error

[image]

this error appear when user want log in in my application.

Comment: Hm..where do you think a problem? When I look at error message, I think that it's a mongodb. And yes, If you take a look at 27017 port - it's a default port for mongodb server. So, have you checked whether mongodb server running or not?

Comment: @TimurBilalov oh my God, I am such a fool, I forgot to running the mongodb, thanks. I am not focuse because I have problem in my last question that not yet get the right answer and it make me little confused. and thanks again for remind me

Comment: change to localhost. I also faced the same problem but in opposite way..

Comment: @NallaSrinivas thanks for the advice, but my problem is not turning on the mongodb, after I turn on it, it work again

Comment: that means you didn`t start the Mongo server?

Comment: @NallaSrinivas yap, my bad sorry